# Replace InputStream by applying regex on it

Tags: java, regex, inputstream

I have an `InputStream` and I need to apply regex on it.  I need an `OutputStream` as a return value since it should be forwarded to api. I do this:

```
// get byte stream
InputStream input = ...;
OutputStream output;

ReplacingInputStream test = new ReplacingInputStream(input, "\\s+", " ");
String inputText = IOUtils.toString(test, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(inputText); // nothing is changed
```

but nothing is changed in  `input`. I couldn't figure out how to do it, so I did

```
String inputText = IOUtils.toString(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
inputText = inputText.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim(); // 
System.out.println(inputText); // Changed
```

This is quick and easy, but of course does not scale nicely to large streams (because perhaps run out of memory)

Comment: are you using the `test` object for the end result?

Comment: You did use `test` as `InputStream` i.o. `input`? Like: `InputStream oldInput; InputStream input = new ReplacingInputStream(oldIInput, "\\s+", " ");`

Comment: I've updated for clarity.

Comment: Check if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079436/change-inputstream-by-applying-regex-on-it) helps

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the 'pattern' parameter is not a Regexp pattern at all and even not a wildcard. It's just a string-to-string replacement.

If we're talking about 'org.apache.poi.util.ReplacingInputStream'.